# How can I assign a vSphere Tanzu license to a Supervisor Cluster programmatically?

Tags: ansible, vmware-vsphere, licensing, powercli, tanzu

I have a vSphere Tanzu license already available in my vCenter Server. Now I want to assign that license to a Supervisor Cluster. It works through the vSphere Webclient manually, but I need to do it programmatically in an IaC context.

I already tried it with the [community.vmware.vcenter_license](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vcenter_license_module.html) Ansible module and the `cluster_name` parameter, but that gives me the following error:

```
Could not assign "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX" (Tanzu Standard activation for vSphere) to vCenter.
```

So, this parameter does not seem to support Supervisor Clusters, just vSAN Clusters.

Is there any other way to do that programmatically? I'm quite flexible on the technology: SSH, PowerCLI, Ansible... would all be fine.